# Java service wrapper to create service for Java UI application

Tags: java, swing, windows-services

I have created a Java application which needs to run as a service. For service wrapper I tried using tanuki and other wrapper softwares.
Now, my application does run as a service - however, it runs as a service under SYSTEM and not under currently logged in user.

My application has a UI, which does not show when the application is running as a service. I doubt that this has happened because the service is running under SYSTEM and not under currently logged in user.
When I run the application (without installing it as a service), the UI does show up and I could see the java process running under the current user's id, whereas it runs under SYSTEM when installed as a service.

Now, there is nothing to my application if there is no UI. I need to application to run as a service when the system boots up and the UI needs to show up as well.

Has anyone tried to do what I am doing here and has faced a similar issue. If so, how did you go about resolving it?
Is there a different wrapper service that I could use and not have this issue.

Tanuki's documentation does explain setting a java application as a service, but does not talk about a java applicaiton with a UI and running it under the currently logged in user.

**Update**

Just so that folks here could get a bit more idea as to what is it that I am trying to accomplish - *the behavior that I am trying to have with my app is similar to how Dropbox or Yahoo Messenger or any other software has which starts with Windows boot and continues to run in the background, allowing the users to interact with it using the system tray icon*.  So basically all of this has been built in Java/Swing. Now when it has come to deployment of the app - I can run it standalone but running the jar file or by creating and running an executable wrapper for it. However, I want the software to start with Windows boot and continue to run as a service in the background, while allowing the user to make changes and interact with it via lets say bringing up the UI from a system tray icon that it sets.
As of now, it does run as a service successfully. It performs all the actions that it ideally should - there just is no system tray icon to bring up the UI and make changes to its configuration.

**Update - 2**

Ok.. I tried advanced installer and it does wrap up everything for me to generate an exe installer for windows. Now all I need is to auto-start the software. Can anyone help me with this? I don't see an option in Advanced installer to automatically have the program add itself up in the auto-start.

Link to tanuki's doc  http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/faq.html

Answer (score 1):

Rohan,
Please take a look at the following page:

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-ntservice-interactive.html

You will need to mark the Service as interactive and then run as the SYSTEM user in order to get your GUI to show up on the first logged in desktop.

The problem is that Microsoft changed what services are allowed to do starting with Windows 2008 and Vista.  This means that starting with these versions, the GUI will always show up on a sandboxed desktop which the user will need to switch over to.

If you want to show a GUI on all desktops, in all versions of Windows, you will need to run the JVM within the desktop.

Cheers,
Leif

Comment: Hi Leif, Thanks for the help. Please find an update to the question which might better depict what is it that I am trying to achieve here. The update starts right below the heading Update in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment on your question, but I don't have enough reputation to do it. So I'm misusing the answer function now.

I have a similar problem. I used the tanuki wrapper for a while now on a Windows XP machine and the Swing GUI was shown to all users who logged in.

Now I migrated to Windows 2008 Server and configured the current version of the tanuki wrapper like this:

```
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=true
wrapper.ntservice.hide_console=true
```

(see documentation [here](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/german/prop-ntservice-hide-console.html) and [here](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/german/prop-ntservice-interactive.html))

The Windows service runs under the LOCAL SYSTEM account.

But the GUI is still not shown. Did you find any solution to the problem?

Comment: Nope.. not yet! We actually tried Advanced installer - it creates a shortcut of the app in the Startup Folder (Windows), which we thought would fire up the application. For some reason it doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you should have a UI with a service. Put it in the startup group instead ?
What's does the UI and application do?

Comment: Hi.. I've updated the question with what is it that I am trying to accomplish with the software.