# Unable to show dialog box using JFileChooser while running on windows service

Tags: java, windows-services, jfilechooser

I'm using the JFileChooser for providing the browsing facility through my service.
When I run the service through command prompt the code runs fine. Whenever I run the service as windows service, browsing dilog box doesn't appear.

Following is my code for the achieving the above:

```
try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) { }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(null), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        chooser.setDialogTitle(title);
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        chooser.setApproveButtonText("Select");
        LOGGER.info("getBrowsedData: before showOpenDialog");
        //chooser.setInheritsPopupMenu(true);
        int temp = chooser.showOpenDialog(new JPanel());
        LOGGER.info("getBrowsedData: after showOpenDialog, temp: " + temp);
        //if (chooser.showOpenDialog(frame) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        if (temp == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            LOGGER.debug("getCurrentDirectory(): " + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
              //File[] uploadDir = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
              List<String> browsedFolders = new ArrayList<>();
              for(File item: chooser.getSelectedFiles()) {
                  LOGGER.debug("folder name: " + item.getAbsolutePath());
                  browsedFolders.add(item.getAbsolutePath());
              }
              return browsedFolders;
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("getBrowsedData: in else showOpenDialog, temp: " + temp);
            LOGGER.error("No Selection for " + title);
        }
```

Comment: the service has probably started java in headless mode which doesnt give you the java graphics system. or its a limitation of windows services (Im just guessing). Do windows services in general have access to the windows GUI? The services need to run independent of a Desktop

Comment: So, a quick google search turned up [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000543/make-an-interactive-windows-service), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553598/java-as-windows-service-with-interactive-desktop-support-and-read-curren-logged) and even [this](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-ntservice-interactive.html)

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer  :)

Comment: to create an interactive service looks toward JavaExe